# d3.json request successfully but got an error message

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get started with d3.js.

It has sent a request and the request was successful.

[image]
[image]

But I got an error message

[image]

Could anyone tell me how do I do to solve it?

Thank you very much!!

My code is as below

```js
var Condt = {
"Condition": {
    "Column": [
        {
            "Name": "Date",
            "Type": "datetime",
            "Value": [
                { "Min": "2018-01-01" },
                { "Max": "2018-09-01" + " 23:59:59" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
};
   
var CondtJson = JSON.stringify(Condt)
var url = "https://cchk3.kingwi.org/AppService/Analysis.asmx/GetStatisticsTotalVolumeForPC?PageSize=10000&PageCount=1&ConditionJson=" + CondtJson;
console.log('url', url);
d3.json(url).then((data)=>{console.log(data);})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The response is not valid JSON as it starts with a left parenthesis `(`! The outermost structure in any JSON representation is either an object or an array, and, thus, the first non-whitespace character has to be either `{` or `[`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @altocumulus said, it looks like the response you are getting is not a valid JSON since it starts with a parenthesis. Looking at the URL itself, it seems your whole JSON is wrapped in `("` `")`

For the future, if you want to catch this error yourself, you can use a `.catch` statement on your promise. See the d3 [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) for examples.